# Objective-C: programmatically share text on instagram direct message or in feed

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to share some text on Instagram either on feed or direct message from my app in iOS. Can anybody let me know How to do that? I've tried the Instagram API Doc but using this Caption is not working the only Image is sharing in feed or story. But in Android, it is sharing text as a direct message using intent.

I've tried the following code:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIDocumentInteractionController *docController;



    -(void)InstagramBtnClick: (id)sender {
        NSURL *myImgUrl = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://www.materials-world.com/bricks/glen-gery/red/images/red_cliff_w12-DA.jpg"];
        NSData * imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: myImgUrl];
        UIImage *imgShare = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://app"];
        if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) //check for App is install or not
        {

            UIImage *imageToUse = imgShare;
            NSString *documentDirectory=[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
            NSString *saveImagePath=[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Image.igo"];
            NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToUse);
            [imageData writeToFile:saveImagePath atomically:YES];
            NSURL *imageURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:saveImagePath];
            self.docController=[[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc]init];
            self.docController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:imageURL];
            self.docController.delegate = self;
            self.docController.annotation = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Testing Caption Text", @"InstagramCaption", nil];
            self.docController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
            UIViewController *vc = [self topMostController];
            [self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectMake(1, 1, 1, 1) inView:vc.view animated:YES];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Instagram App not Found");
        }

    }
```

Is there any other option so that the text can be added in the sharing content in iOS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761932/share-text-with-images-on-instagram-in-ios

Comment: Tried the same but text is not working in captions only image shared using this code

Comment: My Main Objective is to share Text on Instagram along with an Image

Comment: In the link, the latest answer says text cannot be shared anymore. Have a look here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-feed/. There is only an image/video option for iOS.