# Share link/text to Instagram Direct Message on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, instagram, instagram-api, ios-urlsheme

I cannot find any API for sharing text/links to Instagram DM on iOS. I've seen posts that asked similar questions but haven't seen anyone with an answer so I figured I would ask again here. I've seen apps like Spotify able to share an album to Instagram Direct with the link prefilled as message so it's definitely feasible. So just wondering if anyone knows how to get the URL scheme for instagram direct. thanks!

Comment: This may help you https://prograils.com/ios-app-sharing-instagram-whatsapp-facebook

Also see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761932/share-text-with-images-on-instagram-in-ios

Comment: Spotify has closed technical relationships with instagram team.

Answer (score 4):

**A Bit Late To Answer (Aug 2022)**

This is a similar topic that I answered earlier, I was successfully able to achieve the solution, please refer to my solution on the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73213888/4360419

Precisely, there is a deep link available to solve this,

```
instagram://sharesheet?text={anyThingYouWantToShare}
```